# How do I list the API of a Dotnet library?

Tags: c#, .net

I noticed that Azure's Dotnet SDK repository has a [file with a list of the whole public API](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/core/Azure.Core/api/Azure.Core.netstandard2.0.cs) (types/methods/etc) of the library. I assume this is generated using some tool. How can I generate this for my Dotnet library (written in C#)?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [the commit](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/commit/7c3b0ad1c5b2bf91940609d4d67e35cfe39ee980) that last changed that file, it looks like they're using a library called `Microsoft.DotNet.GenAPI`, which it looks like comes from the [dotnet/arcade repository](https://github.com/dotnet/arcade/tree/master/src/Microsoft.DotNet.GenAPI).

I suspect this is probably very closely related to the [Microsoft.DotNet.BuildTools.GenAPI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.DotNet.BuildTools.GenAPI) package that's available on NuGet.

Comment: It seems like this can not be installed in a Dotnet Standard project. Are there any similar tools that work with a Dotnet Standard project?

Comment: I don't know, and before you get too far down that road I'd first ask what your requirements are, really? That C# file is an interesting and concise way to represent an API, but it has no documentation. Most people use [xmldoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/) comments to document their API. That [can be made](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/how-to-use-the-xml-documentation-features) to publish an xml file alongside your dll, which will allow IDEs to show the API and documentation inline.

Comment: XML Documentation [can also be used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15316381/120955) to generate HTML documentation for your API, which will probably be nicer than a bare-bones C# file for anyone who's not using an IDE to look at your API.

Comment: I want to enforce that a library does not introduce any breaking changes in a release accidentally. For this, I need a way to compare the public API of the library with with the previous version's API. Another goal is to detect API changes in the library from a CI environment and prevent accidental breaking changes from being released.

Comment: For Java, I use [japicmp](https://github.com/siom79/japicmp) to do this. I am looking for an equivalent tool for the Dotnet environment.

Comment: It would probably also be relatively easy to write your own tool, especially if having compilable C# as your output isn't one of your goals. It [looks like](https://www.ndepend.com/default-rules/NDepend-Rules-Explorer.html?ruleid=ND1500#!) NDepend also has some features that might help, if you're willing to go for a commercial product.