# How to generate mobile and desktop online documentation from a C# XML documentation file?

Tags: c#, mobile, documentation, desktop

I have a single XML file generated by the C# compiler from the documentation 3 slashs `///` C# syntax.

How can I generate an online documentation that is **both desktop and mobile** friendly?

To avoid any confusion my XML file starts like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
    <assembly>
        <name>APIAsmName</name>
    </assembly>
    <members>
        <member name="T:Namespace1.Type1">
            <summary>
            Type1 desc...
            </summary>
```

---

I insist on **both desktop and mobile friendly** which is not at all addressed in responses of this question [Create html documentation for C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316381/create-html-documentation-for-c-sharp-code)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create html documentation for C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316381/create-html-documentation-for-c-sharp-code)

Comment: @nilsK not really I insist in my question that **mobile and desktop** is an important point because Google nowadays require both (compare to when the other question was asked) thanks for not closing my question